# viewflipper should change background randomly

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a set of backgrounds and I want that when I click a button, which is outside the viewflipper, the next background of the viewflipper should be selected randomly from the set of backgrounds. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess flipper has *`showNext()`* and *`showPrevious()`* only.
**Other Way is:**
You can place your views in a LinearLAyout with their visibility set to "GONE" 
and in the onClick generate a random no using *`Math.random()`*.
Make the visibility of the view at that index in the layout to be visible and others gone.